# Passing Array of data from one chrome extension environment to another

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I have been trying to pass an array of string from a Content Script to Background environment. I know that i have to `JSON.Stringify();` any data, before sending, using `chrome.runtime.sendMessage();` API.

I am just not able to successfully do it. Could someone help we what am i missing?

Thank You In Advance.

**content_script.js**

```
chrome.extension.sendMessage({}, function(response) { //boilerplate taken from extensionizr.com
var readyStateCheckInterval = setInterval(function() {
if (document.readyState === "complete") {
    clearInterval(readyStateCheckInterval);


    var myArr = ["abc", "def", "ghi"];

    alert("in content_script" + myArr);

    var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(myArr);

    chrome.runtime.sendMessage(myJsonString); //send to background environment


}
}, 10);
});
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener( function(response, sender, sendResponse) {

//var data = JSON.parse(response); // gives token 'o' error (object already a JSON Object)
var data = response;

alert("in background.js, received " + data + " \nfrom tab: " + sender.tab.url);

//console.log(typeof youtube_links); // object ...

document.getElementById("results").innerHTML += "1: " + data[0] + "<br/> 2:" + data[1] + "<br/> 3: " + data[2] + "<br/>";



});
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
"name": "test",

"version": "0.0.1",

"manifest_version": 2,

"description": "message passing test",

"icons":
{
    "16": "icons/icon16.png",
    "48": "icons/icon48.png",
    "128": "icons/icon128.png"
},

"default_locale": "en",

"background": //isolated environment
{
    "scripts": [ "background.js"]
    //"persistent": true
},

"browser_action":
{
    "default_icon": "icons/icon16.png",
    "default_title": "default_title goes here",
    "default_popup": "browser_action.html"
},

"permissions": [
    "clipboardRead",
    "contextMenus",
    "activeTab",
    "tabs"
    ],

"content_scripts": [ //user page environment
    {
        "matches": ["https://*/*", "http://*/*"],
        "js": ["content_script.js"] // will run on URLS that match "matches"
    }
]
}
```

**browser_action.html**

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
<head>

</head>
<style type="text/css">
    #mainPopup {
        padding: 10px;
        height: 200px;
        width: 400px;
        font-family: Helvetica, Ubuntu, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
    h1 {
        font-size: 2em;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <div id="mainPopup">
    <h1>Array Data received from content script:</h1>
    <div id="results">

    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

All i get is:

**This as the alert in background.js**

[image: alert("in background.js, received " + data + " \nfrom tab: " + sender.tab.url);]

And **this in browser_action.html**

[image: browser_action.html part]

---

**P.S.** Also, one  more tiny thing. The `alert();` in content_script.js is also not showing for some reason (no errors in the console either)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to stringify your json object. The sendMessage() method can get any valid JSON object as message to send.

In a second time, I don't understand what you're doing with the first call of sendMessage... I think you have to simply delete it and let your code as it is :

Content Script :

```
var myArr = ["abc", "def", "ghi"];

alert("in content_script" + myArr);

chrome.runtime.sendMessage(myArr);
```

Background :

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(response, sender, sendResponse)
    {
        var data = response;

        alert("in background.js, received " + data + " \nfrom tab: " + sender.tab.url);

        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML += "1: " + data[0] + "<br/> 2:" + data[1] + "<br/> 3: " + data[2] + "<br/>";
    }
);
```

EDIT : A litle fix to avoid multiple call :

```
run = function()
{
    alreadyRun = false;

    return function run()
    {
        if(alreadyRun) return;

        if (document.readyState === "complete")
        {
            var myArr = ["abc", "def", "ghi"];

            alert("in content_script" + myArr);

            chrome.runtime.sendMessage(myArr);
            alreadyRun = true;
        }
        else setInterval(run, 10);
    }
}();

run();
```

It's a trick with closure for avoiding the declaration of a global variable.

Comment: Hello @Emrys Myrooin,
I have tried this before and once again now. This doesn't work either.

Comment: the boilerplate i have used already ensures that my page is fully loaded before running the function

Comment: So the litle Content Script I have writen should works. It works for me

Comment: the response data the i receive in background.js  -data[0], data[1], data[2] - should have 'abc', 'def', 'ghi' respectively. But they do not.

In Simplest Words, i need to successfully transfer an array of data from content_script.js to background.js

Comment: Ho You have to enable persitance of background to ensure it is always loaded.

Comment: Try to temporaly delete all code that is not related to the data transfer. It works very well for me

Comment: OH! Your script worked. I suppose that the boilerplate that i have been using must be faulty after all. Thank You for helping out

Comment: Np :-) For the next Question you will ask here, please take care about indentation ;-) It's a litle dificult to read without good indentation

Comment: One tiny issue. The script is now running endlessly (popping up alerts repeatedly). Previously, it would run only once per page load.
Could you indicate what alterations should i make to your script?

Comment: It's weird, I think it's caused by your enviroenement. I edit my answer with a litle trick but I think you have to fix this because this type of infinite loop can be very ressource consuming.